# Imagem não renderiza

Tags: javascript, react

Estou pegando uma imagem qualquer em uma pasta na raiz do projeto e a imagem não renderiza... Fica aquele ícone de imagem com o *alt*. Já olhei em vários tópicos e sites, faço tudo exatamente igual e a imagem não renderiza. No entanto, quando uso o `import` do javascript, ela renderiza normalmente. Estou usando ReactJs.

já tentei:

`<img src={require('../../images/planetsCard/Hoth.png')} alt="planet"/>`

`<img src={'../../images/planetsCard/Hoth.png'} alt="planet"/>`

O quee estou fazendo de errado???

Comment: Com `require` deveria funcionar... Como está o HTML gerado da imagem?

Comment: Você já tentou fazer `require('...').default`?

Comment: Tentei `require('...').default` e não funcionou :/

Comment: O html ta retonando assim : `<img alt="Tatooine" src="[object Module]">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tente importar assim:

```
import planetsCard from '../../images/planetsCard/Hoth.png';

<img src={planetsCard}/>
```

Comment: como eu disse, desta maneira funcionar normalmente, mas não é a opção que posso usar no momento pois a solicitação da imagem está dentro de um map